# How to make a calculation in vb datatgridview

Tags: datagridview

I have a data grid view table in vb.net.In that table i have four columns . "TaxAmnt" ,"RateOFTax","AmntOfTax","AmntAfterTax".I want the calculation just like below.

Example

TaxAmnt      RateOfTax      AmntOfTax           AmntAterTax

10000        4%             400                 9600

25000        6%            1500                 23500

And I want that the total amount is show on the form as  Total 33100

Answer (score 0):

I actually don't know much about VB but I can give a pseudo code simple solution.
I think you are able to access to each row in your datagridview just like doing

```
foreach(datagridviewrow r in yourDataGridViewName.rows){
        double x = r.cells[index].value;
        // and do your needed calculation here
}
```

this is kind of c# code which may be very close to VB code I suppose.